# r adding a group by on dplyr accumulate function

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, accumulate

For a test dataset which is as follows,

```
testdf1 <- structure(list(ShinyUsrId = c(16338, 16338, 16338, 16338, 16338), 
               ButtonId = c(11, 12, 11, 11, 14), V3 = c(1519971165, 
               1520741372, 1520741372, 1521094311, 1513576204), 
              timediff = c(0, 770207, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("ShinyUsrId", 
              "ButtonId", "V3", "timediff"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = 
              "data.frame")


            ShinyUsrId   ButtonId  Button_PressDate       time_diff     
            16338           11     2018-03-02 06:12:45    0
            16338           12     2018-03-11 04:09:32    770207
            16338           11     2018-03-11 04:09:32    0
            16338           11     2018-03-15 06:11:51    0
            16338           14     2017-12-18 05:50:04    0
```

This code below collapses consequent rows where time difference (timediff) is less than 60 seconds.

```
    g <- 0
    Collpase_testdf1 <- mutate(testdf1, date_groups =
                          accumulate(testdf1$timediff, function(x, y)
                            if (y - x < 60)
                              g
                            else {
                              g <<- g + 1
                            })) %>%
     group_by(date_groups) %>%
     summarise(
     ButtonId             = paste(ButtonId  , collapse = ", "),
     ShinyUsrId                = paste(ShinyUsrId, collapse = ", "),         
     time_diff           = paste(timediff, collapse = ", ")
  )
```

So the output looks like this, which is as expected.

```
     date_groups ButtonId        ShinyUsrId                  time_diff                   
       0         11              16338                        0              
       1         12, 11, 11, 14  16338, 16338, 16338, 16338   770207, 0, 0, 0
```

Now if my dataset contains different UserIds like this below

```
       testdf1 <- structure(list(ShinyUsrId = c(16338, 16338, 15148, 84756, 
                84756), 
               ButtonId = c(11, 12, 11, 11, 14), V3 = c(1519971165, 
               1520741372, 1520741372, 1521094311, 1513576204), 
              timediff = c(0, 770207, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("ShinyUsrId", 
              "ButtonId", "V3", "timediff"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = 
              "data.frame")


            ShinyUsrId   ButtonId  Button_PressDate       time_diff     
            16338           11     2018-03-02 06:12:45    0
            16338           11     2018-03-11 04:09:32    770207
            15148           11     2018-03-11 04:09:32    0
            84756           11     2018-03-15 06:11:51    0
            84756           11     2017-12-18 05:50:04    0
```

How do I include group_by parameter so that my output looks like this below

```
      date_groups ButtonId        ShinyUsrId                  time_diff                   
       0         11              16338                        0              
       1         12,             16338                        770207
       2         11              15148                        0
       3         11,14           84756                        0,0
```

I know i can do this using for loop but I am curious how accomplish this using the group_by parameter ?

---

Test Dataset 2

```
testdf1 <- structure(list(ShinyUsrId = c(1765, 1765, 1765, 1765, 
                    1765), 
                   ButtonId = c(18, 18, 17, 17, 121), V3 = c(1519971165, 
                   1520741372, 1520741372, 1521094311, 1513576204), 
                  timediff = c(0, 880, 3502, 13148814, 1210)), .Names = c("ShinyUsrId", 
                  "ButtonId", "V3", "timediff"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = 
                  "data.frame")

            ShinyUsrId   ButtonId  Button_PressDate       time_diff     
            1765            18     2018-03-02 06:12:45    0
            1765            18     2018-03-11 04:09:32    880
            1765            17     2018-03-11 04:09:32    3502
            1765            17     2018-03-15 06:11:51    13148814
            1765            121    2017-12-18 05:50:04    1210
```

Expected output

```
       date_groups ButtonId        ShinyUsrId                  time_diff                   
       0            18              1765                        0              
       1            18              1765                        880
       2            17              1765                        3502
       3            17              1765                        13148814                         
       4            121             1765                        1210
```

---

Test Dataset Scenario 3

```
testdf1 <- structure(list(ShinyUsrId = c(13679, 13679, 13679, 13679,13679,13679, 13679, 13679, 13679,13679, 13679,13679), 
                          ButtonId = c(23, 184, 184, 23, 184,184,23,23,184,184,184,23), 
               ButtonPressDate <- lubridate::ymd_hms(c('2017-11-05 06:34:59', '2017-11-05 06:34:59', '2017-12-07 00:27:53', '2017-12-07 00:53:47', '2017-12-07 01:03:05','2018-03-08 00:28:09', '2018-03-08 00:28:09', '2018-03-08 00:45:02', '2018-03-08 00:45:02', '2018-03-24 13:13:15','2018-05-05 06:22:57', '2018-05-05 06:22:57')), 
                          timediff = c(0, 0, 2742774, 1554, 558, 7860304, 0, 1013, 0, 1427293, 3604182, 0)), 
                     .Names = c("ShinyUsrId","ButtonId", "V3", "timediff"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")




  ShinyUsrId ButtonId     ButtonPressDate timediff
       13679       23 2017-11-05 06:34:59        0
       13679      184 2017-11-05 06:34:59        0
       13679      184 2017-12-07 00:27:53  2742774
       13679       23 2017-12-07 00:53:47     1554
       13679      184 2017-12-07 01:03:05      558
       13679      184 2018-03-08 00:28:09  7860304
       13679       23 2018-03-08 00:28:09        0
       13679       23 2018-03-08 00:45:02     1013
       13679      184 2018-03-08 00:45:02        0
       13679      184 2018-03-24 13:13:15  1427293
       13679      184 2018-05-05 06:22:57  3604182
       13679       23 2018-05-05 06:22:57        0
```

Expected output

```
       date_groups ButtonId        ShinyUsrId     timediff
       0           23, 184         13679,13679     0,0         
       1           184             13679           2742774   
       2           23              13679           1554      
       3           184             13679           558       
       4           184, 23         13679, 13679    7860304, 0
       5           23, 184         13679, 13679    1013, 0   
       6           184             13679           1427293   
       7           184, 23         13679, 13679    3604182, 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your function uses `<<-` operator, I'm not sure you can do it directly. One way would be to split your `data.frame` into a `list` of `data.frames` by `ShinyUsrId` and then use `map_dfr()`, but how about getting rid of `<<-` and `accumulate()` utilizing `lag()`?

```
Collpase_testdf1 <- testdf1 %>%
  group_by(ShinyUsrId) %>%
  mutate(date_groups = cumsum(time_diff - lag(time_diff, default = 0) > 60)) %>%
  group_by(ShinyUsrId, date_groups) %>%
  summarise(
     ButtonId             = paste(ButtonId  , collapse = ", "),
     time_diff            = paste(timediff, collapse = ", ")
  )
```

Comment: thats a good idea but there is something about the usage of lag function and the output is not as expected. It should not collapse the first two rows together because the timediff is 0 and 770207 seconds which is greater than 60 seconds so they should remain separate.

Comment: Sorry, should be `>` instead of `<` in `cumsum()`. Fixed it.

Comment: No issues kwiscion. Looks like there are still some holes in that logic. For example I have updated a my question with a new test dataset at the very bottom of my question and the current solution is combining the last two rows, timediff 13148814, 1210 together. These two should be separate. Any idea why ?

Comment: The code adds `1` to `date_groups` every time the difference between `timediff` in current row and in previous one is greater than `60`. In the example you gave there is `1210 - 13148814 = -13147604`, so less then `60`. Perhaps you expect absolute value of the difference to be checked instead?

Comment: this is my mistake, I apologize, Hope the moderator does not put me on diaper. This will be my last change request I promise. I uploaded one last scenario (test dataset 3) in the question above where the `cumsum( abs(time_diff - lag(time_diff, default = 0)) > 60))` is not working.  It is not combining rows with timediff 7860304, 0 and  1013,0 and 3604182,0. What changes should i make in the cumsum function to accomodate this scenario. This is my last change. No more after this.

Comment: Don't worry, we are here to find a good solution. I am starting to wandering, if the difference of `time_diff` between rows is really what you need. Isn`t it the `time_diff` itself what should be less than 60?

Comment: thanks kwiscion good question  1) the time_diff is the difference in time between two consecutive rows, that is correct. 2) Any consecutive row time_diff that is less than 60 seconds is consider part of the same time instance and hence collapsing them.  For example timediff 7860304, 0  these two rows indicates user click happens at the same time so collapsing them. However  7860304- 0 is not less than 60 but they do occur at the same time instance so this needs to be collapsed. Similarly 1013,0 and 3604182,0.

Comment: In that case, I think `cumsum(time_diff > 60)` is enough. Please edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: I think you already answered the question when you were asked if `time_diff` between rows is really what I need. This made think differently and I used the ButtonPressDate column instead of `time_diff` and it worked perfectly. Thank you again and sorry for the pan cake stacks of questions.